# iterating over vector iterates infinitely

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am using visual studio 2008:

I am trying to iterate over a vector through iterator itrv but it goes into infinite loop for some reason:
Error :

*ERROR* : *Expression: map/set iterator not incrementable*

**Code:**

```
int main(
{
    set<int> s1;
    set<int>::iterator itr;
            s1.insert(43);
            s1.insert(42);
            s1.insert(41);
            s1.insert(3);
            s1.insert(2);
            s1.insert(1);


    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int>::iterator itrv=vec.begin();

    for(itr=s1.begin();itr!=s1.end();++itr)
    {
        cout<<*itr;
        vec.push_back(*itr);
        cout<<endl;
    }

        cout<<"so the size of vector is SIZE : "<<vec.size()<<endl; //i get 6 here

//PROBLEM IN THIS LOOP. GOES TO INFINITE LOOP AND PRINTS JUST '1' INFINITELY
        for(itrv=vec.begin();itrv!=vec.end();++itr)
        {
            cout<<*itrv<<endl;
        }
```

I even tried printing the elements of vector using subscript, it prints fine.
But with iterator it fails:

```
cout<<vec[0]<<endl;
cout<<vec[1]<<endl;
cout<<vec[2]<<endl;
cout<<vec[3]<<endl;
cout<<vec[4]<<endl;
cout<<vec[5]<<endl;
cout<<"with itrv \n";
itrv=vec.begin();
cout<<*itrv;itr++;
cout<<*itrv;itr++;
cout<<*itrv;itr++;
cout<<*itrv;itr++;
cout<<*itrv;itr++;
cout<<*itrv;itr++;
```

Comment: I think you want to use `++itrv` and not `++itr`.

Comment: @Default: see my for loop, i am preincrementing.

Comment: Shame the compilers I tried don't warn about this, but a static analyzer might. Unfortunately, Coliru doesn't have scan-build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(itrv=vec.begin();itrv!=vec.end();++itr)
```

It should be

```
for(itrv=vec.begin();itrv!=vec.end();++itrv)
```

Otherwise, `itrv` was not moved and `itrv != vec.end()` was always true whenever `vec` is not empty.

Comment: oh god! such a silly mistake i have been trying to find it out since long time :((( . Thanks

Comment: Never name two variables with very similar names.

Comment: Good eyes! That was hard for me to even spot! Different variable names would keep simple mistakes from happening.